# Get function parameter from select query

Tags: sql

i have a several table value Function in SQL-2012, i want to get the Function's Parameters as a result

i.e.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MyTempFunction] 
(
    @Para1 char(01) 
    @Para2 varchar(20), 
    @Para3 tinyint
)
RETURNS TABLE
```

need to get the parameter list in a query which is return me as below result with datatype

```
@Para1  Char
@Para2  Varchar
@Para3  Tinyint
```

**Update**

---

need a sql query which is return me a required parameter of function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help full to you

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS where SPECIFIC_NAME = 'Your Function Name'
```

this query also return a data type